# Upgraded to Android studio 3.4 - Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2: Daemon startup failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.4

### I got Error in new project while build after i upgraded Android studio to 3.4

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions were raised by workers
>
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: Failed to start AAPT2 process.
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Process unexpectedly exit.

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:386)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:62)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:268)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:148)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:57)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: Failed to start AAPT2 process.
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopQuietly(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:127)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:114)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.checkStarted(Aapt2Daemon.kt:53)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Process unexpectedly exit.
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:115)
    ... 14 more
```

**here my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file**

```
#Thu Apr 25 11:51:17 IST 2019    
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME    
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME    
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Here is my root level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {    
        google()    
        jcenter()
           
   }

    dependencies {  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'        
       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
   
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
    }
}
 
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is my project level `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "techhunt.com.demo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Here is Build Output window

[image]

**I tried the following:**

1. clean & rebuild
2. restart android studio
3. invalidate caches and restart
4. Delete `C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches` folder and restart Android studio

Opened issue on Google issuetracker by [Izabela Orlowska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8856784/izabela-orlowska) - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131883685

But still these did not solved my issue.

Comment: have you tried disabling instant run ?

Comment: @Umair yes I always turn off  `instant run`

Comment: @NikunjParadva please include app.gradle

Comment: @Basi check new edited question, and for your information it was new project,  nothing changed in that.

Comment: Random guess: Did you try deleting `~/.AndroidStudioX.Y/system/caches` (where `X.Y` is your AS version)?

Comment: @Zoe this was not working

Comment: Perhaps something is blocking your aapt2 executable or there's some mis-match in libraries it uses? Can you locate the aapt2 executabel in ~/.gradle/ cache that matches your current version and try running it from command line?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska nope. but  i deleted ~/.gradle/ cache folder and then check but didn't solve it

Comment: @NikunjParadva deleting it won't help if it's an antivirus blocking it or if there's a problem with the system libraries. Try locating it an calling it by hand to see what the problem is.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska first thing I haven't any antivirus software, and second thing it is working in old gradle version but not work in this new one , and how to locating it and calling it ?

Comment: It will be in C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\<cache>\aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows\aapt2.exe (use files find or something similar to locate it). Once you have it call if from the command line: "aapt2.exe m"

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska yes i cheked i found 6 results inside that 3 of that is working and other 3s are throw error. inside aapt2-3.4.0-{number} folder's aapt2 is not working, but in aapt2-3.3.2-{number} is ready. what to do now?

Comment: @NikunjParadva great! What is the error when you try to run the aapt2.exe under aapt2-3.4.0-{number} ?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska please check this image https://ibb.co/89gSyZs

Comment: Are you using windows 64b or 32b?

Comment: I opened a new issue on Android Studio's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/131883685

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska  64b, thanks for that

Comment: @NikunjParadva did you solve this problem?

Comment: @MansukhAhir till now  not solved.this question.

Comment: @NikunjParadva what does `./gradlew -d app:mergeDebugResources` say?

Comment: same issue. causing aapt2 . and opened issue in bugtracker but still not solved

Comment: @NikunjParadva this is a) not an error description and b) the output would be relevant. alike this question is currently written, without any of those debug resources which crash AAPT2, is rather impossible to answer. please add the `-d` stack-trace and/or push a minimal project to GitHub; so that the actual problem would be understandable/reproducible.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added the stacktrace, and the description also in this question, and second thing i got this error for every project even new project also. and i aslo reported in the issuetracker, and this is not a Off-Topic, please read carefully the whole comments

Comment: @NikunjParadva you did not follow any of my suggestions and refuse to provide the information required to solve the problem. this does not appear too productive and I will simply move on... and that ticket likely will be closed with "information required" (because it might not be reproducible with corrupt/illegal resources).

Comment: @NikunjParadva well, and where is the file-name of the problematic resource or it's XML markup? that the daemon crashes is the result - but likely not the cause of it crashing. the point is, that AAPT2 got more restrictive, outlawing much markup that had been tolerated before (even if it always was illegal).

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? Even I am facing the same issue after updating to 3.4

Comment: @NikunjParadva any possible solution for taking build now? I also posted the same question. And I am unable to take build now... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287239/unable-to-build-android-apk-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresource

Comment: @Encipherer i have face this issue earlier in my both pc, i have install my windows update then the issue was resolved in one pc . i ll do that same for another pc soon

Comment: for me, this solved by installing Rosetta 2, since  i user mac arm architecture,
the command to install
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta
`

Answer (score 8):

I had a same problem. Currently,the best option is to downgrade your class path to the last stable version. For me, i changed my class path to *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'*and it worked for me.
In Android studio 3.4, you can easily downgrade Android Gradle Plugin Version.

1. Go to File->Project-Structure->Project
2. **Change Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.3.2** or the last stable version for you
3. Change the Gradle Version to 4.10.1
4. Click Ok and sync
5. Build Apk

Edit (**Issue solved**): **Installing Service pack 1 for window 7 solved the issue**. The problem was with Universal C Runtime in Windows.

Comment: Downgrade was not solution of this problem.

Comment: I have tried building a new blank project but got the same error. I know it's a workaround. So until Android studio fix some issue here or give any further detail regarding this you can use this solution. May i know, do you able to build apk without any errors with this workaround?

Comment: currently i am working with my old configuration and it works fine, but with new configuration it was not working

Comment: when you upgraded to 3.4, did you deleted the last configurations files which is asked by the installation wizard itself ?

Comment: I had plugin version 3.4.2 and gradle version 5.1.1 and could not build a brand new project. I downgraded to what this answer suggested and worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

When building on Jenkins, if GRADLE_USER_HOME is not specified, it will try to dump the Gradle cache in System32 folder which causes this issue. Changing to a different directory via System Environment variable resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider disabling the `aaptOptions` like the following. Add this in the `android` section in your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

And add the following line in your `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: I see. I ran some searches and came to know that this might also happen for the property of your image files in your drawable folders. Can you please check if you have renamed any png to jpg or vice versa? Are the image files named correctly?

Comment: I thought this thing, but I made new project and i got this error.

Comment: hmm ... Can you please try the updated answer as well and let me know if the problem persists?

Comment: dude still got same issue.

Comment: **DO NOT DISABLE AAPT2!** AAPT has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed, at which point this terrible workaround will break.

Comment: @NikunjParadva Did you got any solution?

Comment: @NikunjParadva Try updating your windows updates. Some issues of mine has been resolved with that. May be it could help you too.

Comment: @DeepakJain not yet helped.

Comment: the option is deprecated and have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

**Project level gradle update classpath:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties update distributionUrl:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

After these steps delete `.iml` file from your project directory and rebuild the project
[For further detail please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spy4c.png)

Comment: Please check my question, I already build the same configuration, and for the `.iml` file i delete  that and then `clean` and `rebuild` but it won't be worked.

Comment: Try to create another new project may be this project has some configuration  files missing.

Comment: I also done it . but not helping me, you should read all information in the quetion, i wrote everything which i had done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File->Project-Structure->Project Change Android Gradle Plugin 
   Version to 3.3.2 or the last stable version for you Let the Gradle
   Version to 5.1.1 Click Ok and sync

it was working but it not use updated gradle 3.4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukCMW.png)

Comment: Downgrade is not a solution,  i know its working in downgrade the Gradle plugin, but it was actually bug in the aapt2 and i registered that on issuetracker.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue. I have tried all the above answers but not working. I have checked these are the questions and their answers. [Question 1](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/358), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287239/unable-to-build-android-apk-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresource), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353745/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks-worke) and I have tried to install **Windows Universal C Runtime library** also.

I have tried to set the Gradle plugin version **3.5.0** and Gradle version **5.1.0 or 5.6.1** but then also not working. I have checked this [google tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131883685) also then also not got the answer.

After spending almost 6 to 7 hours I got the solution and it is below:

1. Android Studio 3.6.2
2. Gradle Plugin Version 3.3.2
3. Gradle version 4.10.3

Project level **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is **gradle-wrapper.property** file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
```

I hope someone will get help.

Comment: as i mentioned downgrade is not a solution. it is a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

For no reason, `./gradlew clean build -x lint -x test`fix the issue while `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` did not and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Use this build.gradle in your project

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fileobserver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

Top level build.gradle downgrade version 
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: as i mentioned downgrade is not a solution.

Comment: Why downgrade is no solution. Android studio development side some issue. that's why not working.