# I Installed Android Studio 3.4 on New PC. Default "Hello World" project is not building

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
10 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 2 up-to-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgraded to Android studio 3.4 - Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2: Daemon startup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861519/upgraded-to-android-studio-3-4-aapt2internalexception-aapt2-daemon-startup-f)

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully build APKs in old 2.1 version, but I  have the same THREE errors in newly installed android studio 3.4.1.

app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE 
app:mergeDebugResources

I tried cleaning project followed by rebuilding then invalidating cache and restarting... Nothing worked. I even uninstalled and reinstalled it, but in vain.

Some how I came to see an error by by clicking a link in error description. The link opened a class file.
 import com.google.generate 
Here generate is shown in RED.... I think this this may be the reason of errors in building. But I haven't found a solution yet. I should be obliged if someone can help.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Build tool bar then choose clean project, try again to build but make sure you’re on the Internet

Comment: Did this before but not getting my issue resolved :(

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'   Downgrade your gradle version

Comment: which grable version will be fit/working for this ?
please reply

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'     Try that

Comment: not resolved yet brother after changing the version