# Unable to build Android APK - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-sdk-tools

Some People marked this question as duplicate. But the issue is still not solved even after I tried all the methods which was given in similar question. aapt2.exe still throwing error and saying aapt2.exe is stopped working.

I have developed a project in Mac machine and it's completely working fine in that. Now I wanted to move this project to another system so that other members can also work in it. When I installed Android Studio and open this same project in Windows machine its showing me the following error and I can't able to generate any build from that system. And I am getting following error in dialog box when I try to take build

```
aapt2.exe is stopped working
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

But I can able to create the new projects in the same machine and take build in that. Only in this migrated project I am unable to take a build. And I checked and changed the **Android build versions and gradle versions, also tried invalidate cache and restart** but nothing solved my problem. Andr my gradle files are...

**App Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sit.novus.novusmobileframework"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //Media Picker
    implementation project(path: ':switchdatetime')
    implementation project(path: ':RTextEditorView-0.1.1')

    implementation  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation  'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation  'com.chootdev:csnackbar:1.3.1'
    implementation  'us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2'
    implementation  'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation  'com.github.marcoscgdev:FingerAuth:1.0.0'
    implementation  'com.erikagtierrez.multiple_media_picker:multiple-media-picker:1.0.3'
    implementation  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Project Gradle File**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle-Wrapper-Properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-projec

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Go to `gradle` option located right of Android studio and then do `assembleDebug`. After that you will see the actual error.

Comment: I tried @SurajBahadur and I got Java JDK issue but still I am getting same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgraded to Android studio 3.4 - Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2: Daemon startup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861519/upgraded-to-android-studio-3-4-aapt2internalexception-aapt2-daemon-startup-f)

Comment: @Zoe but still there is no solution for that problem...????!!!

Comment: I got the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156603/6533853

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run following command from Android studio terminal/ubuntu machine shell.

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleDebug --debug
```

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':switchdatetime:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202 contains a valid JDK installation.

Comment: It appears that your java path is not set properly. Find out where is your java jdk on your system. and then modify gradle.properties file with the following content:

org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_45

Comment: Thanks bro, this solution fixed that jdk problem but still I am unable to take the build and aapt.exe is throwing error saying its stopped working when taking build

Comment: What is the error? share dump of 'gradlew assembleDebug --debug' command.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is Temporary Solution.

use Gradle version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties` change `distributionUrl` to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```