# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Flutter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter

I trying to setup flutter in visual studio code and I am getting below error whenever i run the project. Its the initial main.dart when we create a new flutter project. I tried searching many places but am not able to resolve the issue.

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: I got the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156603/6533853

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having the same issues to date? If so, have you tried running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`? This usually solves common build errors.

An [issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47072) was posted on GitHub similar to what you've described. Downgrading the Android plugin seems to be an option if this issue still persists.