# Android Studio - fail to build "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'."

Tags: flutter, android-studio-3.0

I'm new with Android Studio, and I'm just trying to run the sample code automatically generated for a Flutter project, but I'm having issues while trying to run the build. Here is the error I get on the console:

Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-osx Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please try to add to the question information about the version of Android studio and flutter that you are running, because sometimes those kind of errors are related to specific versions (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861519/upgraded-to-android-studio-3-4-aapt2internalexception-aapt2-daemon-startup-f)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of the plugins. Delete one and run again